# Query Elasticsearch using Spring Data Elasticsearch with fields containing underscore

Tags: spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

Below is my User model

```
@Document(indexName="users",type="records")
public class User{
    private String id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
}
```

and below is my Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User,String> {

    public List<User> findAllByFirst_name(String first_name);

}
```

The above method gives an error of

> No property first found for type User

So I want to know how can I query using fieldnames containing underscores

Answer (score 1):

```
@JsonProperty("first_name")
private String firstName;
```

In @Query you can use `first_name` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171124/searching-a-specific-field-in-elasticsearch-through-spring-data-elasticsearch).

Answer (score 0):

@JsonProperty is not working.
I think only soluntion is use @Query annotation

```
@Repository 
public interface SampleRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<SampleData, String> {

@Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": {\"match\": {\"name_field\": \"?0\"}}}}")
List<SampleData> findByName(String name);
```

}

if you know other way, please comment me.